# How to configure istio helm chart to use external kube-prometheus-stack?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio, kiali, istio-prometheus

I have deployed the istio service mesh on the GKE cluster using **base** & **istiod** helm charts using this [documents](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/helm/) in the **istio-system** namespace.

I have deployed Prometheus, grafana & alert-manager using [kube-prometheus-stack](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack) helm chart.

Every pod of this workload is working fine; I didn't see any error. Somehow I didn't get any metrics in Prometheus UI related to istio workload. Because of that, I didn't see any network graph in kiali dashboard.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: did you enable the sidecar for a namespace ? are you running any demo application and side care getting injected to deployment ?

Comment: Yes, Sidecar was injected using the namespace label. For deployment I can see side car is in running state.

Comment: @ChiragPatel did you get any solution to this. If yes can you paste the solution here

Comment: @dushyant check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/72800789/9134455 I have already pasted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need to add additionalScrapConfigs for istio in kube-prometheus-stack helm chart values.yaml.

```
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
      - {{ add your scrap config for istio }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the above mentioned issue by creating service monitors for data plane and control plane.
Follow below link for more details.

```
https://tetrate.io/blog/how-to-configure-prometheus-operator-scrape-metrics-from-istio-1-6/
```

Answer (score 1):

With prometheus deployed via kube-prometheus-stack helm charts, you will need to add servicemonitor for istio metrics since k8s annotations (`prometheus.io/scrape`)  doesn't work. Create these servicemonitor to enable scraping istio metrics:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: prometheus-oper-istio-controlplane
  labels:
    release: prometheus
spec:
  jobLabel: istio
  selector:
    matchExpressions:
      - {key: istio, operator: In, values: [mixer,pilot,galley,citadel,sidecar-injector]}
  namespaceSelector:
    any: true
  endpoints:
  - port: http-monitoring
    interval: 15s
  - port: http-policy-monitoring
    interval: 15s
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: prometheus-oper-istio-dataplane
  labels:
    monitoring: istio-dataplane
    release: prometheus
spec:
  selector:
    matchExpressions:
      - {key: istio-prometheus-ignore, operator: DoesNotExist}
  namespaceSelector:
    any: true
  jobLabel: envoy-stats
  endpoints:
  - path: /stats/prometheus
    targetPort: http-envoy-prom
    interval: 15s
    relabelings:
    - sourceLabels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name]
      action: keep
      regex: '.*-envoy-prom'
    - action: labelmap
      regex: "__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)"
    - sourceLabels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
      action: replace
      targetLabel: namespace
    - sourceLabels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
      action: replace
      targetLabel: pod_name
```

Once these servicemonitors are created, metrics would start appearing in a few minutes. You can check the status under your `Prometheus -> Status - Targets`   There will be entry something like this:
`serviceMonitor/yournamespace/prometheus-oper-istio-controlplane/0 (1/1 up)` and
`serviceMonitor/yournamespace/prometheus-oper-istio-dataplane/0 (1/1 up)`

Answer (score 0):

Istio expects Prometheus to discover which pods are exposing metrics through the use of the Kubernetes annotations `prometheus.io/scrape`, `prometheus.io/port`, and `prometheus.io/path`.

The Prometheus community has decided that those annotations, while popular, are insufficiently useful to be enabled by default. Because of this the kube-prometheus-stack helm chart does not discover pods using those annotations.

To get your installation of Prometheus to scrape your Istio metrics you need to either configure Istio to expose metrics in a way that your installation of Prometheus expects (you'll have to check the Prometheus configuration for that, I do not know what it does by default) or add a Prometheus scrape job which will do discovery using the above annotations.

Details about how to integrate Prometheus with Istio are available [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/prometheus/) and an example Prometheus configuration file is available [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/addons/prometheus.yaml).